# Restrict type while updating value of variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, types

I have one Javascript variable with assignment of number value to it like :

```
var myVar = 4;

function AlterVar ()
{
   // Here I am changing value of myVar with any thing 

   myVar = 'Changed It ';
}

AlterVar();
```

However, By doing it , now myVar is string. Is there any specific (Without manual coding) which restrict to assign anything other than number type to myVar ?

Thank you !!

Comment: @prasad but then `myVar = 7` would fail..

Comment: If you are looking for statically typed version of Javascript, look for typescript

Comment: You cant alter value of Const until its Object prop !!

Comment: There is no built in way, but pre-compilers can help.. eg.  like @Rajesh said Typescript, or flow -> https://flow.org/  Another option, if myVar was part of an object, you can use Object.defineProperities and use getters / setters.

Comment: As an alternative to static type checking I am currently building a "pluggable" run-time [type checker](https://github.com/kongware/ftor) to address similar dynamic type issues in Javascript. It is based on proxy virtualization (and you cannot virtualize primitives of course, but every other object type and functions). It is far from being finished, but you should get an idea.

Answer (score 4):

There is no check for same type and assigning, but you could use a simple type check for same type.

```js
function alterVar (newValue){
    if (typeof myVar === typeof newValue) {
        myVar = newValue;
    }
}

var myVar = 4;

alterVar('Changed It ');
console.log(myVar);

alterVar(42);
console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina !! But I am looking for something inbuild other than manual check in case possible !!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language. So, you cannot prevent this.

You can add checks to minimize the chances but when it comes to literals, you cannot guarantee.

You can prevent for objects though:

```js
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'testKey', {
  set: function (value){
    if(typeof value === 'string'){
      this.value = value;
    }
  },
  get: function(){
    return this.value
  }
});

console.log(obj)
obj.testKey = '123';
console.log(obj)
obj.testKey = { foo: '123' }
console.log(obj)
```

But if you are looking for completely statically typed language, you should look into Typescript.

#### Reference links:

- [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html)